# Add several divs of same class until browser height is filled

Tags: javascript, html, append

I want to add divs with the same specific height in rows, until the browser window is filled with the divs.

I could do it static, with adding x number of rows where each one has the height of XXXpx to be sure it is filled in (most) resolutions.

```
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
```

However, This will cause problems where I the user will scroll down in vain, and where some users with higher resolution will see whitespace in the bottom of the page.

I would like to do this dynamically. So that one row of 108 px is added, until the screen is filled with rows - No matter the screenresolution.
The rows will be a div which all are the same class, in this specific case with a 108px height.

Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for a responsive design which is likely better to use a framework than try to home brew it. Have you looked at Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I thinks it's no clear what you want from us? A full code-snippet? You should show us what you have tried (for creating the rows dynamically). Then we could help you.

Comment: I have, thank you, actually using skeleton now as a framework. Thing is, I would like to use a script, if that was not clear in my question, sorry, to make divs append until the screen is filled.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I have not tried anything at the moment, since I am completely lost in where I would begin. I could start with making divs append, but I am not sure how I would make the snippet understand how to end when the page is filled.

Comment: @user2883106 can you explain why or what the purpose of running a script retroactively is trying to accomplish? I think you are overcomplicating what might be a relatively simple task.

Comment: Probably you are right, Maybe I am? Well, I have a page which basically consists of rows with different colors, of the same height, where the first two rows will be links, at launch, and the rest of the rows will be link, in time, but for starters, I want the rows to fill the screen, even if they are not links. Just to make a page filled with rows in different colors of the same height. I don't want to make a fixed number static rows since it will be different on different resolutions. If there is a simple way to add rows with a certain height until the page is filled, I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: To clarify, I want the rows to be added automatically on page load.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get the window height and the div quantity, divide them and get the desired height.

**Update**

Now you set the default div height and the script add the divs you need to fill the page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  calculateDivs()
})

$( window ).resize(function() {
  container.empty()
  calculateDivs()
})

//Default height in pixels
var div_h = 108;
var container = $(document.body);

function calculateDivs(){

  //Get window height and substract default page margins
  var w_h = $(window).height() - 20 
  
  //Get div quantity based on window heihgt and div default height
  var divs = Math.round(w_h / div_h);
  
  //Insert div in window (this case in the body directly)
  for(var i = 0; i < divs; i++){
    container.append($('<div class="row">'));
  }
  
  //Margins of the divs (if there is no margin set this to 0)
  var margin = 5

  //Set height to all appended divs
  $('.row').css('height', w_h / divs - margin)
}
```

```css
.row{
 margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

With

- `window.innerHeight`
- `window.addEventListener("resize", function() {})`

Clear the innerHTML of the **container** every time the window is resized

`container.innerHTML = ""`

Number of rows

`Math.floor(window.innerHeight / height)`

Create divs in a loop and add them to the container.

#### Example

(Container is vertically centered)

```js
function makeRows(dh) { // div height
  var h = window.innerHeight,
    container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0],
    l = Math.floor(h / dh);
  container.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.height = dh + "px";
    div.style.border = "3px solid brown";
    div.setAttribute("class", "row");
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  makeRows(108);
});

makeRows(108);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* Vertically center the container */
  display: table;
}

.container {
  /* Vertically center the container */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```